# Jetbrains Rider Plugin Trigger Build

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am currently building a plugin for Rider, and unsure how to trigger a build of a project. 
I am getting the current active project, but cant see how to build this.

```
public void Execute(IDataContext context, DelegateExecute nextExecute)
{
        IProject pro = context.GetData(JetBrains.ProjectModel.DataContext.ProjectModelDataConstants.PROJECT);
}
```

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development is the best place to ask.